# Python - Numpy - Converting a numpy array of hex strings to integers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of hex string (eg: ['9', 'A', 'B']) and want to convert them all to integers between 0 255. The only way I know how to do this is use a for loop and append a seperate numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

hexArray = np.array(['9', 'A', 'B'])

intArray = np.array([])
for value in hexArray:
    intArray = np.append(intArray, [int(value, 16)])

print(intArray) # output: [ 9. 10. 11.]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could there be strings for numbers that are equal to or greater than 10? Also, by better, what are you looking for? Compact or more performant?

Comment: @Divakar I want it to take the least amount of time to convert. This example only has a few values but I'll have arrays with 1000s of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vectorized way with array's-view functionality -

```
In [65]: v = hexArray.view(np.uint8)[::4]

In [66]: np.where(v>64,v-55,v-48)
Out[66]: array([ 9, 10, 11], dtype=uint8)
```

**Timings**

Setup with given sample scaled-up by `1000x` -

```
In [75]: hexArray = np.array(['9', 'A', 'B'])

In [76]: hexArray = np.tile(hexArray,1000)

# @tianlinhe's soln
In [77]: %timeit [int(value, 16) for value in hexArray]
1.08 ms ± 5.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# @FBruzzesi soln
In [78]: %timeit list(map(functools.partial(int, base=16), hexArray))
1.5 ms ± 40.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# From this post
In [79]: %%timeit
    ...: v = hexArray.view(np.uint8)[::4]
    ...: np.where(v>64,v-55,v-48)
15.9 µs ± 294 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: `hexArray = np.array(['9', 'A', '1B'])` where `1B`-->`27` using thise code I get output `array([  9, 208,  10, 208,   1,  11], dtype=uint8)`.How to make it work for any value not just for *1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f*

Comment: @Ch3steR That was my [`question as comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868884/python-numpy-converting-a-numpy-array-of-hex-strings-to-integers#comment107693092_60868884), there was no response and also since the title had `hex` strings, I assumed it's all one character strings. I guess OP would come back if they have such scenarios too.

Comment: I'm not saying this answer is bad or complaining. I just wanted to know how to convert every hex string to int.

Comment: @Ch3steR I didn't assume you were. For that, we need to process further on `v`, won't be very pretty tho.

Answer (score 3):

With the use of list comprehension:

```
 array1=[int(value, 16) for value in hexArray]
 print (array1)
```

output:

```
[9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using map:

```py
import functools

list(map(functools.partial(int, base=16), hexArray))
[9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
intArray = [int(hexNum, 16) for hexNum in list(hexArray)]
```

Try this, uses list comprehension to convert each hexadecimal number to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good one:

```
int_array = np.frompyfunc(int, 2, 1) #Can be used, for example, to add broadcasting to a built-in Python function 
int_array(hexArray,16).astype(np.uint32)
```

If you want to know more about it: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html?highlight=frompyfunc#numpy.frompyfunc

Check out the speed:

```
import numpy as np
import functools
hexArray = np.array(['ffaa', 'aa91', 'b1f6'])
hexArray = np.tile(hexArray,1000)
def x_test(hexArray):
    v = hexArray.view(np.uint32)[::4]
    return np.where(v > 64, v - 55, v - 48)
int_array = np.frompyfunc(int, 2, 1)
%timeit -n 100 int_array(hexArray,16).astype(np.uint32)
%timeit -n 100 np.fromiter(map(functools.partial(int, base=16), hexArray),dtype=np.uint32)
%timeit -n 100 [int(value, 16) for value in hexArray]
%timeit -n 100 x_test(hexArray)
print(f'\n\n{int_array(hexArray,16).astype(np.uint32)=}\n{np.fromiter(map(functools.partial(int, base=16), hexArray),dtype=np.uint32)=}\n{[int(value, 16) for value in hexArray][:10]=}\n{x_test(hexArray)=}')
460 µs ± 2.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.25 ms ± 2.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.11 ms ± 6.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
16.8 µs ± 165 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
int_array(hexArray,16).astype(np.uint32)=array([65450, 43665, 45558, ..., 65450, 43665, 45558], dtype=uint32)
np.fromiter(map(functools.partial(int, base=16), hexArray),dtype=np.uint32)=array([65450, 43665, 45558, ..., 65450, 43665, 45558], dtype=uint32)
[int(value, 16) for value in hexArray][:10]=[65450, 43665, 45558, 65450, 43665, 45558, 65450, 43665, 45558, 65450]
x_test(hexArray)=array([47, 42, 43, ..., 47, 42, 43], dtype=uint32)
```

Divakar's answer is the fastest, but, unfortunately, does not work for bigger hex numbers (at least for me)